# Formatting chapter headings using the titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

I'm trying to do a very simple task but I'm a beginner in LaTeX, so I have some doubts.

I'd like to change the chapter style. Instead of

Chapter 1

Introduction

I'd like to have

**C H A P T E R 1** (bold, centered, underlined and one single space between the letters)

Introduction.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure if something like this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}% juts to generate text for the example

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\filcenter\underline{\MakeUppercase{\textls[400]{\chaptertitlename}}\ \thechapter}}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that underlined bold-faced text might be a bad dasign choice.

Comment: Perhaps! I will try without the underline. Just to check: wich command do I have to use to generate an italic text in CHAPTER 1?

Comment: @Gustavo You're welcome! You can add `\itshape` just before `\MakeUppercase` to have italicized font

Comment: I tried to figure out how to adapt this to use an 'english' rule using `swrule` but no matter what I do, the result looks like a few blocks stuck together. Not that it matters if the underline is being dropped but maybe I misunderstood what that is supposed to do...

Comment: @cfr Perhaps something like this? `\newlength\ChapNamNumWd

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\settowidth\ChapNamNumWd{\MakeUppercase{\textls[400]{\chaptertitlename}}\ \thechapter}\filcenter\MakeUppercase{\textls[400]{\chaptertitlename}}\ \thechapter\llap{\raisebox{-6pt}{\swrule{\ChapNamNumWd}{2pt}}}}{20pt}{\Huge}`

Comment: Precisely. But the results look like ugly boxes. That is, the lines I get are not smooth at all however much I increase the counter which is meant to control how fine-grained the gradations are. (At least, default is 50 and I tried at least 20000 with no significant improvement.) I just double-checked and I get the same with that code as I did with mine. (Not surprising as did essentially the same thing.)

Comment: @cfr yes, the result is far from good. I had never used `swrule` before, but I think one can produce something more pleasant without it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you are right. I've never used it either. I just remembered vaguely that there was such a package and thought it might offer a better option than underlining (which doesn't look good to me).